# How can I add layouts for a device with custom resolution?

Tags: android, layout, android-screen

I have an application in which added designs for 7" tablets in a folder sw-600dp and 10" tablets in a folder sw-800dp.

They work fine but now I want to add layouts for a device with resolution 768 * 1024 and screen size 7.85". How can I add layouts for this screen?

I have tried adding folder sw-768dp in project but it does not getting layouts from that folder.